# Random number does not update every time I call the function

Tags: python

I am writing a game, "Guess the number". Initially, the computer chooses a random number in the range 0-99 and the player guesses what number it is. Once the player's guessed the number, the game starts again.

The player can restart the game at any time, using two buttons: 
"New game. Range is 0-100"
and
"New game. Range is 0-1000"

[image]

Here's the link to an online editor, where you can view and edit the file:

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_1sYMUy5rDi_0.py

For now, the number that the computer chooses is always printed, but once the game works correctly, it'll be removed.

Anyway, the problem is, that when the user enters the number the computer chose, the game restarts, but the same number is chosen by the computer as last time. But if the user clicks on the new game button, a different number is chosen by the computer, which is correct.

The logical error occurs here:

```
num_range = random.randrange(0,100)

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    print "Guess the number!"
    global secret_number
    global num_range
    secret_number = num_range
    print secret_number
```

If I remove the

> secret_number = num_range

line from the new_game() function and replace it with

> num_range = random.randrange(0,100)

every time the user correctly guesses the number, a new game starts with a different number in the same range, which is correct, but a I need variable, so that the two buttons work. Do you know how to use the variable num_range so that every time the game starts automatically after the user has guessed the number, the secret number's different than the last time?

Here's the entire program:

```
import simplegui
import random
import math

num_range = random.randrange(0,100)

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    print "Guess the number!"
    global secret_number
    global num_range
    secret_number = num_range
    print secret_number


#event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global num_range
    num_range = random.randrange(0,100)
    global secret_number
    secret_number = num_range
    print "The range is 0-100"
    new_game()

def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    global num_range
    num_range = random.randrange(0, 1000)
    secret_number = num_range
    print "The range is 0-1000"
    new_game()

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic
    g = int(guess)
    # remove this when you add your code
    print "Guess was", g
    if g <secret_number :
        print "Higer"
    elif g > secret_number:
        print "Lower"
    else:
        print "Correct"
        print "Starting a new game..."
        print ""
        new_game()


# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess the number",200, 200)
frame.add_input("Enter your guess", input_guess, 200)
frame.add_button("New game. Range is 0-100", range100, 200)
frame.add_button("New game. Range is 0-1000", range1000, 200)
# register event handlers for control elements and start frame


# call new_game 
new_game()
```

Comment: You're only defining the random number when you first run the program.

Comment: Somebody has to post the link: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: *"Random number does not update every time I call the function"* - ...you **never ask it to**.

Comment: @FredLarson That's so sony-like !  Now, for the question, it's because the number is only generated when you call it(so at the beginning).

Comment: @pwnsauce That isn't the problem. Python's random seeds automatically

Comment: @JohnColeman gosh I always initialised my seed u_u but the [Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) is totaly on your side !

Comment: @pwnsauce I also did that for the longest time before reading that it was superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it the quick but not so ugly way.

First, let's create a new global variable `max_number = 100`

Then, the changes you must do to `new_game()`

```
def new_game():
    print "Guess the number!"
    global secret_number
    global max_number
    secret_number = random.randrange(0,max_number)
    print secret_number
```

Finally, replace `range100()` and `range1000()`'s definitions by :

```
def range100():
    global max_number
    max_number = 100
    print "The range is 0-"+str(max_number)
    new_game()

def range1000():
    global max_number
    max_number = 1000
    print "The range is 0-"+str(max_number)
    new_game()
```

Comment: Why did I not think of that? Thanks!